# How to populate Table View with a .plist file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, plist

hey guys,
I created a Table View with Navigation Controller, in a Tab Bar Application. This is the code I used to populate my Table View with data:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Glossary", @"Back");

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Title1", @"Title2", @"Title3", @"Title4", @"Title5", @"Title6", @"Title7", @"Title8", @"Title9", nil];
self.glossaryArray = array;
[array release];
```

}

So there are my 9 data examples that I created manually using that array string, but I want to make things easier, how can I populate my Table View using a .plist file? I have a big plist file that I want to load into my Table View, but I don't know how to code it in, hope I can get help with this,

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array from your plist just by creating it with :

```
+ (id)arrayWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath
```

To find the path of your plist file, you can use `NSBundle`'s

```
- (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension
```

Comment: what about this? - (void)viewDidLoad {
 // load from plist
 NSString *myfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
       pathForResource:@"exercise" ofType:@"plist"];
 exercises = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myfile];
 
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

Comment: One little comment, you should call super before your other stuff (the only exception is dealloc) :)

Comment: thanks! works perfectly! much more easier than putting everything in one string array!